# Thread affinity with Async in WinRT context

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, winrt-async

I want use an existing code using ThreadStatic for implementing a per thread singleton (like Transaction.Current)

However, it doesn't work with the async/await model running in a new Task. I know that since SynchronizationContext.Current is null, ThreadPoolTaskScheduler is used and the continuation can be in another thread.

For exemple, if i execute the following code :

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{                    
   Debug.WriteLine("Start on thread {0}", Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
   await Task.Delay(10);
   Debug.WriteLine("Continue on thread {0}", Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
});
```

The result is :

Start on thread 5

Continue on thread 4

My singleton implementation is something like this :

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static long? _sessionIndex; // Immutable value
private static ConcurrentDictionary<long, ...> contexts;
public static ... Current 
{
  get { 
    return contexts[_sessionIndex ?? (_sessionIndex=Interlocked.Increment(..))];
  }
}
```

Stephen Cleary propose [another solution](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html) based on a "singleton per ExecutionContext" which works perfectly in a 4.5.1 context but doesn't work with the limited winrt platform (CallContext doesn't exist)

As a solution, i would try to force the continuation execution in the same thread than the main task to keep the ThreadStatic mechanism.

Implementing a TaskScheduler could be a solution but you can not manipule thread in winrt.

Perhaps with a specific SynchronizationContext but i don't found how. 
I'm afraid that is not possible.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5):

I have a couple types [`AsyncContext` and `AsyncContextThread`](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext&referringTitle=Documentation) in my [AsyncEx library](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/) which define a single-threaded context. They provide a custom `TaskScheduler` and `SynchronizationContext`.

The `AsyncContextThread` works by taking a task from the thread pool, installing a main loop, and keeping that task until all the asynchronous operations complete. A "return to the same thread" task scheduler / synchronization context must operate this way because there is no way to queue thread pool work to a specific thread.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen. You save my life ;-) Just another question, does ConfigureAwait(false) break the synchro ?

Comment: @AlainMetge: Yes; `ConfigureAwait(false)` tells `await` to *not* use the `SynchronizationContext` (or `TaskScheduler`).

Comment: Stephen, When i try to use one of your unit test with winrt, the task is blocked.
The code is : Async(async () => { var context = new AsyncContextThread(); await context.Factory.Run(() => 2); await context.JoinAsync(); }); with Async public static void Async(Func<Task> test) { test().Wait(); } How can i exit from the task ?

Comment: (Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a forum site. You posted a followup question as an answer to your previous question; next time, please post a new question.) You're running into a [classic deadlock situation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I describe on my blog. The solution is to use an `async` unit test instead of the `Async` method.